# How to modify a ShareViewController so that choosing an app in the share sheet results in saving media and launching the selected app?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

The ability to import media files from various apps (like Photos, Files, WhatsApp) to an app I am building (referred to as "My App" from hereon) using a share button is what I am seeking to achieve.

The user interaction process should be as follows:

**Step 1**: Select media file from any app

**Step 2**: tap share button which should list "My App" among others

So far, I have been able to get my app listed on the sharesheet sorted based on [this article](https://medium.com/macoclock/ios-share-extension-swift-5-1-1606263746b). I have also looked at this [post](https://www.appcoda.com/ios8-share-extension-swift/) that makes use of `SLComposeServiceViewController` which caters to the more of a social media like popup from a sharesheet. Neither of these have helped reach a solution.

However, I am unable to achieve my desired outcome from user action of selecting "My App" from the sharesheet, which is:
a. have selected media copied into a directory accessible to "My App"; and
b. launch "My App" in the View that shows the contents of this directory. (As the capitalisation of View demonstrates, I am writing "My App" in SwiftUI.)

Working through the aforementioned tutorial, I was unable to figure out how to achieve the described outcome; this might have to with my quite limited experience of to manipulating UIViewControllers, which I have managed to avoid so far with SwiftUI.

Any guidance on this matter would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For those looking for a pure SwiftUI and code-only approach way of solving the problem of importing media/data into your app, the most straightforward solution I found was to use `.fileImporter` in a View. An excellent explanation and example code is available [here](https://betterprogramming.pub/importing-and-exporting-files-in-swiftui-719086ec712). The only drawback is that your app is not on the sharesheet but that is okay, in my opinion/use case.

The beauty of this solution is that:

1. It is code only and doesn't require you to mess around with the info.plist file to define the UTI as per [this tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/8413525-universal-type-identifiers-tutorial-for-ios-importing-and-exporting-app-data)
2. better yet, you do not deal with the Share Extensions and the corresponding ShareViewController, which is no fun to figure out for a purely SwiftUI-based developer.